# NextJS: directly forward request to backend and response to client in /api

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

My project stack consists of a `Next.js` server to handle front-end and a separate back-end server to store user data etc,.

When a client wants to send a request to the back end, they send an API request to the `Next.js` server, which then gets data from the separate back-end server.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to forward these requests to the server and the response from the server to the client without data being lost, or the code being very messy.

This is what I'm using right now:

```js
export default function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse){
    fetch(url, {
        method: "post",
        body: req.body
     }).then(response => res.status(200).json(response.body))
}
```

Obviously, with this solution, the headers are lost. I *could* manually add a headers field, but that was just an example. There are lots of other fields to add, and I'm looking for a way to include *all* of them.

**Important Note**: the reason I have to intercept the request is to insert JWT token.

Comment: Are you using App Router or Pages Router ?

Comment: @Beast80K App router!

Answer (score 1):

I have a backend in node js and a frontend in Next js I am using this approach and I found it very amazing

````
    export const resendSingupOtpAction = action({}, async () => {
      const res = await fetch(
        `${process.env.BACKEND_BASE}/users/resend-signup-otp`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { ...getAuthorizationHeader() },
        }
      );
    
      if (!res.ok) {
        return getApiError(res);
      }
    
      const { messsage } = await res.json();
      return { success: messsage as string };
    });
   
    export const setSecureJwt = (tkn: string) => {
      cookies().set(COOKIES.JWT, tkn, {
        secure: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: true,
      });
    };
    
    export const deleteSecureJwt = () => {
      cookies().delete(COOKIES.JWT);
    };
    
    export const getApiError = async (response: Response) => {
      const data = await response.json();
    
      return {
        error: (data?.message?.length
          ? data.message[0]
          : 'server_error') as string,
      };
    };
    
    export const getAuthorizationHeader = () => {
      const token = cookies().get(COOKIES.JWT)?.value;
      if (!token) return false;
      return { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token };
    };
    
    
    export const getJsonTypeHeader = () => {
      return { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    };
    ```
````

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35772269)